Where is the UltraPLONK paper?
I'm looking for the paper for UltraPLONK, the extension to Turbo PLONK that Aztec released in 2020. I'm seeing references to it in other papers (but with no link to the actual paper) and in social media platforms of Aztec. Everything implies that there is a paper on UltraPLONK, but it's nowhere to be found. So is there really no paper or am I just failing to locate it? Can someone help me find it?



I think UltraPlonk is TurboPlonk with Plookup https://docs.zkproof.org/pages/standards/accepted-workshop3/proposal-turbo_plonk.pdf & https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/315.pdf

Found no paper. On UltraPLONK itself a most linked page is this. For a related bibliography see below "Papers issued" there. Also this recent paper and it's references, including this, which also aims at being PlonK + plookup. I don't know enough about the subject to tell what papers are worth reading, thus won't make an answer.

It is fair to say that, in ZK-land, hackmd is a strong contender to eprint.iacr.org. AFAIK there aren't any formal papers. The most "complete" write-up I know of is probably the halo2 book: https://zcash.github.io/halo2/concepts/arithmetization.html

The above suggests this Google query, which is fruitful.

This is still helpful. I think it's true that there was never a formal paper. Thank you all very much.
